# Regular expression to clean up names

Tags: python, regex

I have two dataframes of names. The dataframe is longer, but I am using top3 as examples.

```
First list name examples: 
JOSEPH W. JOHN
MIMI N. ALFORD
WANG E. Li

Second list name examples:
AAMIR, DENNIS M
MAHAMMED, LINDA X
ABAD, FARLEY J
```

I need to extract the first name in those two dfs, how can I extract them in one regular expression.

```
The return should be 
list 1
JOSHEPH 
MIMI
WANT

list 2
DNNIES
LINDA
FARLEY
```

My current code looks as `re.search(r'(?<=,)\w+', df['name'])`, but it didn't return the right name. Is it possible to write two regular expression code in Python to extract those names?

Comment: So are those `**` literally present in your input?

Comment: no, they are the name that I wanted

Comment: `(?:[^,\n]*, |^)([a-zA-Z]*)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/59IfjE/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what you want to look for here is the first sequence of word characters that *does not* have a comma anywhere *after* it on the line, rather than one that *does* have a comma *before* it. So instead of your positive look-behind assertion, it seems that you will want a negative look-ahead assertion.

Try using as your regex:

```
r'\w+(?!.*,)'
```

Apply this using:

```
df['name'].apply(lambda name:re.search(r'\w+(?!.*,)',name).group())
```

Applying the above to this example dataframe:

```
                name   foo
0     JOSEPH W. JOHN     1
1     MIMI N. ALFORD     3
2         WANG E. Li     3
3    AAMIR, DENNIS M     3
4  MAHAMMED, LINDA X     3
5     ABAD, FARLEY J     3
```

gives:

```
0    JOSEPH
1      MIMI
2      WANG
3    DENNIS
4     LINDA
5    FARLEY
```

Comment: how should it be applied in regular expression, what's the code

Comment: @LearningCode I've added how to apply it.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what does each symbol mean? like above

Comment: Hi @alani could you explain a little more on the code? the regex command

Comment: @LearningCode I've already given a high-level description of the regex. If you want a symbol-by-symbol description, have you come across the regex101.com site? Go to https://regex101.com/r/zsPiEV/1 and in the top right you will see an explanation of every symbol in this regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
df['First Name'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'(?:(?<=^(?!.*,))|(?<=, ))([A-Z]+)', expand=False)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vdP3hM/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ', '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```