# regex code, how to slove some data entry error

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have two dataframe

```
df1

name
ADAM, HAFIZ M
ABAD, FARLEY J
CORDDED, NANCY C
BOMBSHAD, WANG D

df2
JOSEPH W. HOLUBKA   
WANG E. JONATHAN
CUCU F. LIU,
WANG C. DANA,
LANDY F. JON
```

I am hoping to extract the first name of each dataframe. For df1, I need the "first name" portion after "," , the second df, the first name is what I want.

so the returned df is

```
df1
HAFIZ
FARLEY
NANCY
WANG

df2
JOSEPH
WANG
CUCU
WANG
LANDY
```

my current code is

```
  df['name'].str.upper().apply(lambda name:re.search(r'\w+(?!.*,)',name).group())
```

This regex works for both df, however, I just realized my data has an entry error. In df2, Liu and Dana have a "," at the end which cause the regex to not working.

the error is group() is not an attribute.

Is there anyway I could fix this code? the regex should work for both df

Comment: With the answers to your last, very similar question it should not be a too big deal to figure it out. You just need to invest a little bit of willingness to learn... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269362/regular-expression-to-clean-up-names

Comment: Won't simply doing this `re.search(r'\w+',"CUCU F. LIU,")` work for you. I am assuming you only have one word as the first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(^(?=[^,]*,?$)[\w'-]+|(?<=, )[\w'-]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbfbU8/2/). This pattern allows matching a name at the initial position in the string if there is a trailing comma in the string.

Use it in Pandas with `Series.str.extract` vectorized method:

```py
df['first name'] = df['name'].str.upper().str.extract(r"(^(?=[^,]*,?$)[\w'-]+|(?<=, )[\w'-]+)", expand=False)
```

**Regex details**

- `^(?=[^,]*,?$)[\w'-]+` - one or more word, `'` and `-` chars (`[\w'-]+`) at the start of the string (`^`) if the string has no commas but may end with an optional comma (`(?=[^,]*,?$)`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<=, )[\w'-]+` - one or more word, `'` and `-` chars chars preceded with comma + space.

Comment: If I have a name with "-" in the middle, for example John-Smith T. Ronald, is there anyway to capture that? Also, is there anyway to make it all capitalized without using str.upper()? Thank you

Comment: @LearningCode Making it uppercase without `str.upper()` is impossible, Python `re` does not support `\U` / `\u` operators in the replacement patterns.  To match names with hyphens and apostrophes, replace `\w` with `[\w'-]`, `(^(?=[^,]*,?$)[\w'-]+|(?<=, )[\w'-]+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbfbU8/2/).

Comment: sorry, it says invalid syntax when I put it in, the invalid mark is on "]

Comment: it says invalid syntax when I put it in, the invalid mark is on "]"

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: Trying this again because my first one wasn't all there.  You can take the regex from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64270085/10431574) and you only need to change one thing.  Where their lookahead matches any comma, we only want to match a comma that is followed by another word.  Resulting in:

```
(?:(?<=^(?!.*, *\w))|(?<=, ))([A-Z]+)
```

Comment: this regex doesn't work for both df, for the first one, I want to return name after ","

Comment: It's a valid regex, it's just capturing the thing you want in a different position.  I'm not a python user so there are [certain operands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) which are specific to python that I'm not too familiar with.  If I add `?:` to the first parentheses `(?:\, *|^)(\w+)` then the first name moves from group 2 match to group 1 match.  I'm not sure (yet) how to not capture the `, ` at all and have the first name be the full match.  But you might find the answer in that doc I linked.

Comment: You can specify the group when you call `group()` rather than returning the whole match. 
 Does this work for you? `df['name'].str.upper().apply(lambda name:re.search(r(\, *|^)(\w+)',name).group(2))`

Comment: Ok I realized my error.  It **is** matching the correct name, but it's also matching the incorrect name.  Basically it is matching twice on group 1.

Comment: thank you, this is working for df2, but for df1, it sometimes only catch few letters, not the full name

Comment: thank you, this is working for df2, but for df1, it sometimes only catch few letters, not the full name –